# Navigation submenus don't slide out. Is my javascript not working?

Tags: jquery, slider, navbar

I'm a newbie so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here!

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alh3168/UwG7h.

I'm trying to make a simple fly-out navigation menu where the sub-menus slide out to the right of the navigation menu. I want it to be similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/ReuLr/6. I've tried everything; is it possible to make this CSS instead of javascript? Do you see any mistakes in the rest of my code that is preventing the slideout navbar from working? Thanks in advance!

Here's my javascript, which I just copied from the previous jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var secs1 = $('ul.first > li');
    secs1.hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the example you provided, I made the following modifications:

- Removed the `h1` tag from your HTML
- Put the `navigation`'s `style` attribute value into CSS
- Added some CSS for the elements `div.menu ul`

[Here's a Fiddle including the modifications made](http://jsfiddle.net/M4U2w/)

***Notes:***

- the JS code was not modified (it's the same as your example's JS code).
- when using JSFiddle, don't forget to select jQuery from the "Frameworks and Extensions" list ;)

---

**CSS:**

```
#navigation {
    background-color:#FFF;
    height:100%;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}

/********************/
/* MENU            */
/*******************/
 div.menu {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
/* ADDITIONAL CSS */
 div.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
div.menu ul li {
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
div.menu ul.first li a {
    width: 190px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #00293E;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
div.menu ul.first li a:hover {
    background-color: #B2CC7F;
    color: #00293E;
}
div.menu ul.second {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    width: 190px;
}
div.menu ul.second:hover {
    display: block;
}
div.menu ul.second li a {
    width: 190px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #B2CC7F;
    color: #00293E;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 10px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
div.menu ul.second li a:hover {
    background-color: #597A5E;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <header id="header-main">
        <img src="Logos/headerlogo.jpg" width="215" height="80" longdesc="Logos/headerlogo.jpg">
        <hr size=1 width=175 align=left style=margin-left:35px>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="first">
                <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Blog</a>

                    <ul class="second">
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Sub category 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Sub category 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Sub category 3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Sub category 4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Sub category 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Sub category 6</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="" title="" runat="server">Instagram</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Store</a>

                    <ul class="second">
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Etsy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Society6</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Portfolio</a>

                    <ul class="second">
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Capstone</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Visual Communications</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Illustration</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Photography</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Painting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Printmaking</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Fibers</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Contact</a>

                    <ul class="second">
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">E-mail</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="" title="" runat="server">Linked In</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr size=1 width=175 align=left style=margin-left:35px>
        <ul id="search-list">
            <form method="get" action="http://www.andreahock.com">
                <table cellpadding="0px" ; cellspacing="0px">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-style:solid none solid solid; border-color:#C93;border-width:1px;">
                            <input type="text" name="zoom_query" placeholder="  search the blog" style="width:150px; font-family: Neou-Bold; src: url('Neou-Bold.otf'); font-size:8px;letter-spacing:1px ;border:#FFF; height:17px; padding:0px 3px; position:relative;">
                        </td>
                        <td style="border-style:solid; border-left:#FFF;border-color:#C96;border-width:1px;">
                            <input type="submit" value="" style="border-style: none; border-left:#FFF ;background: url('jpegs/magnifyingglass.jpg') no-repeat; width: 20 px; height:23 px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
<div id="content">Content goes here</div>
<div id="footer" style="background-color:#DABC69; font-family: Neou-Bold; src: url('Neou-Bold.otf'); font-size:10px;letter-spacing:1px; clear:both; text-align:center;">All designs belong to Andrea Hock</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul ul').each(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).find('ul.second').stop(true, true).animate({
                width: "toggle"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 250
            });
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).find('ul.second').stop(true, true).animate({
                width: "toggle"
            }, {
                queue: false,
                duration: 250
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It's still not working when I put it in Dreamweaver for some reason. No idea why because it works perfectly in jsfiddle.

Comment: Only other question I have is how to make the height of the fly-out menu 100%.

Comment: @user3344592: Hi mate! I think you should post this as a new question to get more answers and advice :). Also you may try to provide a screenshot of what you'd like to have.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to call the javascript properly! That's why it wasnt working in dreamweaver. Thank you for your help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('ul ul').each(function () {
    $(this).parent('li').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "toggle"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 450
        });
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('ul.second').stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "toggle"
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 450
        });
    });
});
```

});